# java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext Serialization stack: - object not serializable

Tags: java, apache-spark, serialization

The error can be reproduced in the spark-shell.
Basically, I define a class with a method for producing an RDD and then I perform a map operation on the RDD which generates the serialization error.

If I don't have the method and just have statements that perform the steps of the method, then everything works.

The code is here which can be run in spark-shell I define a class and then I instantiate the class.

First the imports

```
import java.nio.file.{Files}
import java.io._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.io.Source
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
```

Here is the class with a method and a map with anonymous function to count separators in a string

```
class DataValidation(datasetPath: String, datasetName: String, separator:    
String, encoding: String, sc: SparkContext) extends Serializable {

// open file and load distribute... and try playing around with it...
// RDD data declaration, reading dataset on RDD without header

var dataset = datasetPath + "//" + datasetName + ".csv"

def textfile_encoding(datasetIn: String, encodingIn: String) : RDD[String] = {
var characters = ArrayBuffer[String]()
    for (line <- Source.fromFile(dataset, encoding).getLines()) {
         characters += line
    }
sc.parallelize(characters)

}
val rdd = this.textfile_encoding(dataset,encoding)
val separatorCount = rdd.map(_.count(_ == separator.charAt(0))) //error here
println("here")
}
```

Then here are the calling statements

```
val encoding = "utf8"
val datasetName = "InsuranceFraud"
val datasetSeparator = ";"

val sc = new SparkContext("local", "DataValidation Application")

val DataValidation = new DataValidation(datasetPath, datasetName,
datasetSeparator, encoding, sc)
```

The error i get is

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@2aa98145)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$DataValidation, name: sc, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$DataValidation, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$DataValidation@3d93cd9c)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$DataValidation$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$DataValidation)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$DataValidation$$anonfun$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:312)
    ... 87 more
```

PLEASE Note the following behavior

1. If I change a statement in the class as follows then everything works.

   `val separatorCount = rdd.map(_.count(_ == ';'))`
2. If I inline the method i.e just execute the statements within the method and not have a method, everything works too.

Answer (score 2):

Ive resolved this now..

Since Im using separator in my map function, serialization is attempted on the whole class. However, the method textile_encoding cannot be serialized causing the error.

So, I've moved this method to a separate class and instantiated it externally and passed it to this class.

Now serialization is fine.

When you have this problem you have three solutions I think:-

1. Do what I did. Move method to a different class
2. Write your own closure/serialisation. (Don't know how yet)
3. Pre-Serialise the offending method (Don't know how yet)

Regards

Amer